# compare special string in sql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, compare, substring

Im new using sql. 
Im trying to compare a content of column **type** in my table **client**.
If this column begin with XXX then I want to create new column with specific value cat1. 
If this column begin with XXY then CAT2, If this column begin with XYY then CAT3,

```
select  name, if SUBSTRING(type, 1, 3)=='XXX' then 'CAT1' as x2
from client.
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `case`.  And I would recommend `like`:

```
select  name, (case when type like 'XXX%' then 'CAT1' end) as x2
from client;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`. For example:

```
select
  name,
  case when type like 'XXX%' then 'cat1'
       when type like 'XXY%' then 'cat2'
       when type like 'XYY%' then 'cat3'
  end as category
from client
```

Comment: Ok thank you. To detect the end of string. I want to detect rows where type begin with XYY and ends with C1 I did **when type like 'XYY%'  and type like '%C3' then 'cat3'**

Comment: No unfortunately I have rows with XYYBNPC1 and its NULL :/

Comment: @salsa Please accept this answer and ask another question for the new requirements.